# On the Center of $GL(n, \mathbb K).$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field and $n\in\mathbb N.$ Prove that the Center of $GL(n, \mathbb K)$ is $\{kI_n| k\neq 0\}.$

I know a solution as follows:

Let $A$ belong to $GL(n, \mathbb K).$ Fix $1\leq i\neq j\leq n.$ Denote by $E_{ij}$ the matrix with $1$ as $(i, j)$ coefficient, and $0$ elsewhere. Then $(I_n + E_{ij})$ belong to $GL(n, \mathbb K).$ So $$ (I_n + E_{ij})A = A(I_n + E_{ij}) \Leftrightarrow E_{ij}A = AE_{ij}.$$
Then $A = kI_n$ with $k\neq 0.$

However, we see that if $A = \begin{pmatrix} a &b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in GL(2, \mathbb R)$ and $E_{12} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$
then $E_{12}A = AE_{12}$ if and only if $a = d,\ c = 0$ and any $b\in\mathbb R.$ This means $A\neq aI_2$ with $a\neq 0.$
Note that $E_{12}A  = \begin{pmatrix} c &d\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $AE_{12}  = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &a\\0&c\end{pmatrix}.$

I hope someone can explain this to me. Thanks!

Comment: Every element in the center of a group has to commute with every element in the group. Your $E_{12}$ is not an element of the group because it has determinant 0.

Comment: What @JCAA says, $b=0$ by replacing $E_{12}$ with $E_{21}$.

Comment: @Quang Hoang Thank you very much!